# joomla pagination - every page has the same articles

Tags: joomla, pagination

In the `ContentModelCategory` class, in the `getItems()` method, I have the following settings for the pagination object:

```
JPagination Object(

  [limitstart] => 0
  [limit] => 5
  [total] => 14
  [prefix] => 
  [_viewall:protected] => 
  [_additionalUrlParams:protected] => Array()
  [_errors:protected] => Array()

  [pages.total] => 3
  [pages.current] => 1
  [pages.start] => 1
  [pages.stop] => 3
)
```

After which I return the articles.

When I look at the page, I indeed have pagination with 3 pages.
Problem is that every page has the same 5 articles.

How can I fix this?

Regards,

Matthijs

Comment: Can you show me your full getItems and getListQuery Methods?

Comment: Hello, Matthijs did you get solution for this? I am also having same problem